# Unit Tests with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner fails loading context with PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, junit

I am trying to write some unit (integration) tests with Spring. I am using the SpringJUnit4ClassRunner. I have written tests using this runner before in my domain layer without an issue. Now that I'm trying to write tests in my web application and get the 'Failed to load ApplicationContext' exception.

The application is based on Hibernate / JPA 2.0. Here is the main exception:

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:641)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:91)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:288)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1485)

Comment: Can you post your classpath? Judging by the stacktrace you have mixed JPA versions in your classpath.

Comment: My main app runs without issue and its using the same pom file. Which jars should I be looking for? I'm using Maven so I can't post the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Thans for the tip M. Deinum. I looked through my pom file and noticed that Spring Skyway Software Utils where bringing in JPA1. Once I removed the Skyway utils, my unit tests started to work.